# Overruns in newtheorem in latex

Tags: line-breaking, theorems

I'm defining a newtheorem as follows:

```
     \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
```

the problem is when the definition name is long, it results in overruns. I've tried `\\` to split the name in two lines, but it's not working.

Here is relevant part of my tex file:

```
 \documentclass{vldb}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{url}
 \usepackage{times}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
```

and then I use:

```
   \begin{definition}[anonymity non-reconstructible fragmentation]
```

and `anonymity non-reconstructible fragmentation` causes overrun.

btw, vldb package is a pre-defined package I can't alter.

Comment: Which package are you using to define your structures? Can you please add a simple, complete document showing the definition and the problem in action?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about the `vldb` class, but the clues you give suggest it's two column. With the `amsthm` package you get what you want  and are also able to set the font in the body of the definition to upright, which is customary:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[anonymity non-reconstructible fragmentation]
aaa
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `subfigure` has been obsolete for ten years; prefer `subfig` (possibly with the `caption=false` package, that might be required with the class you're using).

Answer (score 4):

If the default `\newtheorem` is used, then the optional argument (your `definition` title) is set in a box as part of a list, hence being unbreakable. With minimal manual intervention, you can fix this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[anonymity non-reconstructible fragmentation and then some]
\lipsum[1]
\end{definition}
\begin{definition}\textbf{\upshape(anonymity non-reconstructible fragmentation and then some)}
\lipsum[1]
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The class `vldb` uses the kernel's `\newtheorem`, but with a redefinition of `\@opargbegintheorem`; as with the original definition, the annotation is placed as part of the optional argument of `\item`, so no line breaks are allowed. To correct this you can redefine `\@opargbegintheorem` so the annotation will be outside the optional argument for `\item`; with the appropriate settings you will respect the style used by the class.

Unfortunately, in this specific case, the word at the end of the line "fragmentation" will break at "frag" producing an overfull box (by `1.48pt`), so perhaps a manual line break could be used. The example below shows two possible alternatives:

```
\documentclass{vldb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\trivlist
\item[\hskip\dimexpr\labelsep+10pt\relax{\scshape #1\ #2}](\textsc{#3}).\ \itshape}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[anonymity non-reconstructible fragmentation]
\lipsum[4]
\end{definition}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{definition}[anonymity non-reconstructible \\ fragmentation]
\lipsum[4]
\end{definition}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]